# Add to existing contact

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook

I am trying to replicate the iPhone's default behavior for adding a phone number to an existing contact. To clarify, I am talking about the UI, not programmatically.

My first attempt was to present an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and when the user selects a person, present a `ABNewPersonViewController` with the selected person. The problem with this method is that if the user hits the cancel button, the contact is deleted from the address book.

Answer (score 3):

You should be implementing the `peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:` delegate method (as it is required), and you can save the person back if you need.

A (probably better) way to handle it, would be to copy the address book, present a `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` with the copy, and then when the UI is finished, you will know if you should keep the original (if someone got deleted on accident ?) or replace it with the copy with the added information.  Hope this helps! Also, take a look at Apple's QuickContacts Sample Code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuickContacts/Introduction/Intro.html)!

Edit for how to copy an address book's people array:

```
// Fetch the address book 
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *copy = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook)
```

Another Edit: A good place to start in the developer guides for this is the ABAddressBook docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/userexperience/Reference/AddressBook/Classes/ABAddressBook_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: How can you copy an address book?

Comment: it's been a while since I've looked at this framework, have you looked through Apple's QuickContacts sample code? I recall it being useful. Edit: i added the copy code to my original answer.

Comment: I added a fair amount of info to the original answer, including a link to ABAddressBook (the base object for address book work) and a link to the QuickContacts sample code from apple.